# "I can feel/hear/see someone" or simply "I feel/hear/see someone"

Tags: verbs, differences, word-usage

I'm confused as to when one should use "can" and "could" before verbs such as "feel", "hear" and "see".

Does it make a difference in any way when you do include "can" or "could" in front of a verb of perception?

Here are some example of sentences using the perceptive verb "feel". Some use "can" before it, others don't. Does it make a difference to the meaning?

1. **I feel** someone grab me from behind.
2. **I can feel** his body tense next to mine.
3. **I feel** a strange calm as I look at him.
4. **I can feel** the anger boiling up inside me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the examples 1 and 3 you acutally do feel something with no alternative of not doing it.
You can not actually miss the grabing hand except you had a numb area on your skin.

In those cases with odd numbers there is actually a possibilty not to feel because of (let's call it) missing empathy.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  I believe the question involves use of "can". and "could" , rather than whether the senses are actually involved.

Comment: If  I understand correctly, you are asking if there is a difference between 'I feel X' and 'I can feel X'. No, I don't think there is.

Comment: I think you've come up with what might be the nub of the answer here. But I'll need a bit of time to really think about it.

Comment: Yes; I think one usually uses 'feel/felt' when it would be remarkable not to, and 'can/could feel' when others less perceptive in the relevant domain might well not do. // There are, as might be expected, grey areas: 4'/4" _I felt / could feel the anger boiling up inside me._ // 5' / 5" _She felt / could feel his eyes upon her._ Probably, the punctive / durative aspect involved also informs choice here.